# How to read text displayed on the window pop up on UL class by selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to read the text displayed on the popup window in Web driver using Java. I am able to handle the popup window for closing. I don't know how to read the text displayed on Popup window and print it in Console.

HTML :

```
<ul class="traceInner"><li class="traceHead"><span><input type="checkbox" class="chkall hand">奖期</span><em>追号倍数</em><em>追号状态</em><em>注单详情</em></li><li><span><input type="checkbox" rel="20151119031YCL02WY0001" class="hand disabled" disabled="disabled" name="2015316">2015316</span><em>1</em><em><label>已完成</label></em><em><a class="hand traceDetails" data-id="20151119031YCL02WY0001" rel="434">详情</a></em></li><li><span><input type="checkbox" rel="" class="hand" name="2015317" 追号中="">2015317</span><em>1</em><em><label>进行中</label></em><em>&nbsp;</em></li></ul>
```

I need to get the lable text of 已完成 in label.

MY CODE :

```
ConfirmationPlaceBet_Page.verification_ZhuiHao2(driver).getText();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You can use this xpath for general :

```
xpath = //label[text()= '已完成']
```

2.If you have too many ul element then use this xpath :

```
xpath = //ul[@class='traceInner']//label[text()= '已完成']
```

3.If you want to get first label element then use this xpath :

```
xpath = (//ul[@class='traceInner']//label)[1]
```

Note : Pass 2 instead of 1 if you want to get second label

4.If you want to get list of labels then use this xpath :

```
 xpath = //ul[@class='traceInner']//label
```

Here is your answer of "How to get text" :

```
 String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your Xpath")).getText();
```

**Warning**

For List of web elements you have to use like this :

```
 String text_1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your Xpath of List")).get(0).getText();
```

Comment: No need to thanks :). Happy to give contribution in this tech world. :)