# how to use the xpath when there is more than one match for given xpath?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have more than one match for xpath: `//button[contains(.,'View Details')]`. how can I locate the first instance or the particular instance for `View Details`?

```
<div class="ma-center-button">
    <button class="button button--secondary ma-center-button--block" data-ui-sref="myAccount.billing.recent-charges" href="/my-account/billing/recent-charges">View Details</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need the first one, just use, assuming you are using Java, `findElement()`:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'View Details')]"));
```

There are certainly other ways to locate the button, but, given what you've provided, how about checking the `href` to end with `recent-charges`:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[href$=recent-charges]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Append [1] to the Xpath expression to get the first item in the sequence.

Comment: Please provide full solution

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(.,'View Details')][1]")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have already give answer [How to use xpath in Different way ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798007/how-to-read-text-displayed-on-the-window-pop-up-on-ul-class-by-selenium/33799242#33799242)

You can use xpath like this :

```
(//button[contains(.,'View Details')])[1]
```

Here you can pass 2,3,.. instead of 1.

Comment: @E.Praneeth Can you share your question with HTML ? I am not sure why its not working for you ?